# How to emit value from the catch block of Kotlin flow

Tags: android, kotlin, try-catch, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have the below function which works with Kotlin flow

```
sealed class State<out T> {
    data class Loading<out T>(val progress: Int = 0) : State<T>()

    data class Success<out T>(val data: T?) : State<T>()

    data class Error(val exception: Throwable) : State<Nothing>()
}

suspend fun getReviews(movieId: Long): Flow<State<List<Review>>> = withContext(IO) {
    flow { emit(api.getReviews(movieId)) }
        .map { it.sortedWith { item, _ -> if (item.userId == pref.getUserId()) -1 else 0 } }
        .map { State.Success(it) }
        .catch { error -> emit(State.Error(error)).also { Timber.e(error) } }
}
```

I'm unable to emit an error state from the catch block when there is an exception. It gives me an error stating `Type mismatch: inferred type is State.Error but State.Success<List<Review>> was expected`

Why can't I emit the sub class of the State from the catch block?

Comment: Change `.map { State.Success(it) }` to `.map<State<X> { State.Success(it) }` where X is your data type.

Comment: `.map { State.Success(it) }` is inferred as `Flow<State.Success<T>>` but `State.Error` is not a subtype of `State.Success`